# Can we have both outgoing channel and incoming channel in single one api

Tags: hibernate, apache-kafka, quarkus, mutiny

From end point I will get json format data,first I will publish it in Kafka using emitter and I need to get it from the Kafka topic in the same api and store it database using hibernate,
But when I reciving message ,it will close the pool and return to end point and then excite the incoming messages and because of this I can't have instance for the class and store it database. Please give suggestions

I tried using @Incomming
@channel("kafka-in")
With fun() to get the Kafka,when running this it will stop running and return the response,

Answer (score 0):

Yes, Kafka can be an Incoming and Outgoing channel, however, this is where you would use Kafka Streams rather than SmallRye's Consumer/Producer channel models.

Regarding the database, [apache-kafka-connect](/questions/tagged/apache-kafka-connect) is often a better solution.